# How to store this.state data in variables?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do some kind of typeRacer game and I encountered a problem when trying to get this.state into a variable. here's the code

```
class TextViewer extends Component {
    state = {
        loading: true,
        quote: null,
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "https://api.quotable.io/random?minLength=200";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({quote: data, loading: false});
                console.log(data);
    }
```

This is just the data fetching, but I wanted to show the declaration of state

```
    timeCalculatorStart() {
        var today = new Date(),
            hour = today.getHours,
            minute = today.getMinutes + 60 * hour,
            seconds = today.getSeconds + 60 * minute;

        this.state = {
            StartTime: seconds,
        };
    }

    timeCalculatorEnd() {
        var today = new Date(),
            hour = today.getHours,
            minute = today.getMinutes + 60 * hour,
            seconds = today.getSeconds + 60 * minute;

        this.state = {
            EndTime: seconds,
        };

        this.timeCalculator();
    }
```

These are the functions I use for declaring this.state.EndTime and this.state.StartTime

```
    timeCalculator() {
        var score = this.state.quote.length / (this.state.EndTime - this.state.StartTime)  
        // here is where I get the error " 'score' is declared but its value is never read. "
    }
 
    render() {
        return (
            /*
            there is code that works here, without using the TimeCalculator()
            */
                <div>
                    <form>
                        <input
                            className="input-text"
                            onInput={this.timeCalculatorStart()}
                        />
                    </form>
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-submit"
                        onInput={this.timeCalculatorEnd()}
                    >
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'score' is declared but its value is never read.` is not a compilation or runtime error, you are just not using the variable. In your case, you are not returning it, so from that function, you get nothing.

That is what you might want to do:

```js
timeCalculator() {
    return score = this.state.quote.length / (this.state.EndTime - this.state.StartTime);
}
```

Another **bug** I extracted from you code is that, you are directly mutating the `state` and that's exactly what you shouldn't do. For example:

```js
// you are the devil
this.state = {
    StartTime: seconds,
};

// this is what you should do instead
this.setState({
    StartTime: seconds
})
```